# New Toshiba Satellite Pro - Ctrl key not working in certain programs

Tags: keyboard, toshiba-satellite

I've just bought a new laptop (Toshiba Satellite Pro C50D). As a webdesigner, I use the program Sublime Text and there's a command to expand codes. This command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on my laptop is working fine for other uses (copy/paste for instance) but in this program it doesn't do anything. I know nothing changed in the program itself because I have the same version on my old laptop and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is working fine there.

What I can do to solve this problem (instead of using an external keyboard)

Comment: I hope you are facing this problem on Ubuntu and not on Windows 8. I am asking this because you had tagged the question with [tag:windows-8] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bought a new laptop, then I am assuming you have installed the latest version of Sublime Text. `CTRL + E` is working, just that your Sublime Text installation is not recognizing it because it is now part of the `vintage_ctrl_keys`.

Check here on how to enable `vintage_ctrl_keys` -> [Enable Vintage Package](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html)